# EOS error while pushing transaction

Tags: transactions, eosio-code

I received an error while pushing a transaction onto the jungle test net[image: A screenshot of the action fields from bloks.io.]

[image: A screenshot of the code that is being tested]

Comment: Please provide code for this error

Comment: i add the code you can check

Comment: the name sagar is not existed on jungle

Comment: did you configured your chain_id carefully, I mean instead of this did your other contract working fine using this jungle test configuration?

Comment: can you show me how you defined your table ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting it cannot locate user `sagar`.

The `require_auth` line will error if it cannot locate the user or it cannot locate the necessary signature.

You should first create an account with the name you expect on the Jungle testnet, then verify its existence https://jungle.bloks.io/account/sagar.

Once you created the `sagar` user and imported the key to your wallet, you can sign and push transactions as that user.

Comment: Thanks for your help